# Convergent of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

[image]

For this question, I can successfully prove that the series of |sin(n^0.5)|/n^1.5 converges but I don't understand why the solution can just say " |sin(n^0.5)|/n^1.5 converges, hence the original series (-1)^n sin(n^0.5)|/n^1.5 converges absolutely." Can someone please explain me why the solution can say the negative case converges straight away but no need to use the Alternative Series Test?

Answer (score 2):

If a series converges absolutely then it's a convergent series. The proof is based on the Cauchy criterion for the convergence of the series.

Comment: But then how can I know does the series converge absolutely or conditionally ?

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane The way the terminology is usually used, I don't think a series can be both absolutely convergent and conditionally convergent.

Comment: Yes you're right I mean then the series is convergent.

Comment: @user84413 Obviously absolutely convergent and conditionally convergent is mutually exclusive to each other. But how do you guys know the series is convergent absolutely by testing |sin(n^0.5)|/n^1.5 converges without testing (-1)^n sin(n^0.5)|/n^1.5?

Comment: Since the series of absolute values converges (by comparison to $\sum\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$, as described in the answers above), the original series converges absolutely by definition.

Comment: @user84413 Thank you, that is useful. Can you also please tell me more about conditionally converge? I found these two are so confusing.

Comment: If the series of absolute values diverges, but the series itself converges, then it is conditionally convergent.  Some simple examples are $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{1}{n}$ or $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: @user84413 So if the series of absolute values diverges, but the series itself converges, then it is conditionally convergent.
If the series of absolute values converges, then the series itself will also converge and we call it converge absolutely. It that right?

Comment: @user84413 Sorry, I accidentally added the comment before I finished. I just edited the comment.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

The alternating series test is actually not applicable here because one has no idea what the sign of $\sin(\sqrt{n})$ is.  However, the solution is just to use the comparison test.  This eliminates both the $\sin$ factor and the sign factor.  Then, one uses the integral test or the dyadic summation test together with geometric series if you like to verify that $\sum_{n\ge1} 1/{n^{3/2}}$ converges to a finite value.

Answer (score 1):

You may just write that
$$
\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{\sin(\sqrt{n})}{n^{3/2}}\right|\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\frac{\sin(\sqrt{n})}{n^{3/2}}\right|\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}
$$
and your initial series is absolutely convergent **thus** is convergent, where we have used the fact that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{3/2}} $ is convergent.

Comment: By writing your first quantity, don't you already implicitly assume the series converges?

Comment: I understand this one. But how do I know a series is converge absolutely or just conditionally if I don't verify both the positive and negative series?

Comment: @ClementC. I understand your point now, please, see Sami Ben Romdhane's answer. Thanks.

Comment: @OlivierOloa How do I prove a series is convergent absolutely? Is it if series with absolute value and the original series both are convergent, then the series is said to be converge absolutely, if either one diverge, then we say its conditionally converge?